# Draft JS Header Toggles Not Working With Tailwind CSS

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, draftjs

I am using Draft Js for Rich text editor in my react project that uses tailwind.
H1-H6 have no effect when toggled on texts.
The other block types (blockquote, ul, ol, code-block) work.

I have tried changing 'style' to className and use a tailwind class but it isn't working.

`{label: 'H1', className: 'text-2xl'}`

Any idea on why this isn't working?

Comment: See the tailwind typography plugin

Comment: I ended up using react-draft-wysiwyg

Answer (score 1):

Draft.js and `react-draft-wysiwyg` use defined by you in your project. TailwindCSS does not define the style of heading as explained [in their docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#adding-base-styles)

In order to have styled heading without changing your base styles, extend `global.css` with the following code:

```css
.DraftEditor-editorContainer h1 {
  @apply text-4xl;
  @apply font-bold;
}
.DraftEditor-editorContainer h2 {
  @apply text-3xl;
  @apply font-bold;
}
.DraftEditor-editorContainer h3 {
  @apply text-2xl;
  @apply font-bold;
}
.DraftEditor-editorContainer h4 {
  @apply text-xl;
  @apply font-semibold;
}
.DraftEditor-editorContainer h5 {
  @apply text-lg;
  @apply font-semibold;
}
.DraftEditor-editorContainer h6 {
  @apply text-sm;
  @apply font-semibold;
}
```